# French slang question? (eighteenth-century)

Tags: sens, traduction, argot

I'm reading an old comic play from 1715 and I'm struggling to interpret a word:

> Leandre suit comme un lâche,
>   Scaramouche est un ***gavache***;
>   Et moi itou.

I think it might be:

> Leandre follows like a coward,
>   Scaramouche is a foreigner [derogatory?]
>   And I am also.

This does not entirely make sense in this context (or any context). If there are any slang shades of meaning that might improve my understanding, it would be much appreciated.

*Disclaimer: So sorry if this word is offensive or a swear. I am unaware. [I don't believe it is, but if so, my apologies.]*

Comment: Vulgarity is part of language, and it should never be considered offensive to discuss any word in the context of examining meaning, usage, or etymology. Somewhat analogous to "Fear of a name only increases fear of the thing itself."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "gavache" would be either a "personne lâche" (a coward) or a "nom dédaigneux donné à des personnes d'origine étrangère au pays" (i.e. a disdainful name for foreigners) as per [TLFi/CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gavache).

No worries about offending anyone, this word probably has no impact at all these days, it is completely dated, and rare. I didn't know/remember this word at all when I saw this post.

Comment: *Gavache* would still be understood in Roussillon where is is still quite an offensive word to name people from the neighboring Aude, and also in a large part of former "Langue d'Oc" area for people still familiar with Occitan, but not in Provence where *gavot* would be used instead. See http://www.etymologie-occitane.fr/2011/09/gavach-gavatch-gavot/

Answer (score 3):

In Spain, *gabacho* is still used to refer to French people, probably originating from the Napoleonic wars. It is somewhat pejorative.

Comment: "Somewhat pejorative" is an understatement :-)  and it's older the the Napoleonic wars, although they definitely help popularize it. *Gabacho* probably started to be used in Spanish to call the Frenchmen as early as the 16th century and comes from a Occitan/Catalan derogatory word (*gavach/gabatx*) from at least the 13th century. Funnily, *gabacho* is now used in Mexico to call US citizens.

Comment: @jlliagre true, but in my city we named an street after some _gavatxons_ that lived there. It's pejorative in general but also colloquial. Near that street is another named after _bastard_. We definitely have a sense of humour here.

Comment: Then there must be an *avinguda dels franxutes* ;-)